# Problem with multiple SqlDataReader and SqlCommand in a Class

Tags: c#, sql-server, class, sqldatareader

I have a problem with C#, I have a Class with a function for SqlDataReader and another for SqlCommand (the first one is just for read values from a DataBase and the second one is for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ... in the same DB).

The problem is, for the first part of the code (the login), I have to search the values from an Active Directory (it works), then I must see if the user has username and password in my own DB (it works), and then, if the user is not in the DB then I have to create it and get the ID, if it is already created then I just have to get the ID.

The problem is that I get this message :

> InvalidOperationException was
>   unhandled by user code
>
> There already exist an Open DataReader
>   associated with this Command, who as
>   to be closed first.

There is the code :

**Class.cs :**

```
    private static string MyConnectionString = "THIS IS MY CONNECTION";
    private SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
    public SqlCommand MyCommand = new SqlCommand();
    public SqlDataReader MyReader = null;

    public void DBMyReader(String SqlQuery)
    {
        if (MyConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            MyConnection.Open();

        MyCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
        MyCommand.CommandText = SqlQuery;
        MyReader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    }

    public void DBMyUpdate(String SqlQuery)
    {
        if (MyConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            MyConnection.Open();

        var cmdTest = new SqlCommand();

        cmdTest.Connection = MyConnection;
        cmdTest.CommandText = SqlQuery;
        cmdTest.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    public void DBMyInsert(String SqlQuery)
    {
        DBMyUpdate(SqlQuery);
    }
```

** Login.aspx.cs: **

```
                    MyClass.DBMyReader("SELECT util_codi,util_logi,util_nome FROM Tgep_util WHERE util_logi='"
                            + Session["username"].ToString() + "'");
            MyClass.MyReader.Read();

            if (!MyClass.MyReader.HasRows)
            {
                MyClass.MyReader.Close();
                MyClass.DBMyInsert("INSERT INTO Tgep_util(util_logi,util_nome) "
                            + "VALUES ('" + Session["username"].ToString() + "','" + Session["nome"].ToString() + "')");
            }

            MyClass.DBMyReader("SELECT util_codi,util_logi,util_nome FROM Tgep_util WHERE util_logi='"
            + Session["username"].ToString() + "'");

            MyClass.MyReader.Read();

            Session["user_id"] = MyClass.MyReader["util_codi"].ToString();

            Response.Redirect("FRM_Principal.aspx");
```

Edit : Update Code (Works for now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means exactly what it says..  You have loaded a SQLCommand and started reading rows, and are now trying to do an insert.  You need to close out that reader first, or use a new command.

in the DBMyUpdate function you could just create a new command:

```
public void DBMyUpdate(String SqlQuery)
{
    if (MyConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        MyConnection.Open();
    var cmdUpdate = new SqlCommand();

    cmdUpdate.Connection = MyConnection;
    cmdUpdate.CommandText = SqlQuery;
    cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
}
```

edit: based on comments to this answer, it required using separate connections which seems odd/incorrect.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. The problem is that if I close the Reader i have to start another time de query i don't know if it is very eficient... Is there a solution tu solve the problem only using the classe ?

Comment: @aliasbody I just added a way to alter your DBMyUpdate function to use a new command that should not conflict with your existing reader.

Comment: Don't worry about efficiency until your code works. You don't want fast broken code.

Comment: With your code I got the same error... It doesn't make any sense since I use a new SqlCommand...

Comment: @aliasbody are you sure this was recompiled?  just making sure, because that doesn't sound right to get the same error..

Comment: I have already recompiled the project (Build, Clean, Rebuild etc...) and the same error... Is there anything to do with the connection ?

Comment: @aliasbody does it tell you what line # the exception is failing on?  Are we sure its the update function?  You could try a new connection, not as a final solution, but just to troubleshoot...

Comment: Hi again (ps: thank you for all your help), the line that the exception is falling on is the MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); on the DBMyUpdate when the Insert is made in the Login file. I have already tried to create 2 diferent SqlCommand variables one for the Update and another one for the Insert and the same error occur

Comment: @aliasbody ok.. did you try using a unique connection for the insert function?

Comment: It works but only for add the user, because when I tried a second time to login (and create) delete the user, i get the same error in the MyDbReader

Comment: @aliasbody It seems like there's a bigger problem with this data access layer you've created, which is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: But I really dont understand Why, I have only 1 connection, I make a read then and insert than try to read the already open DataReader and get the values...

Comment: PS : is there a possibility that the problem occurs because the Connection is static ?

Comment: I have solve the problem removing the static and changin the code... I don't know it that affect any of the other code of the program but only time and testes can tell me... (I will update the code on the post... I really don't want to repeat the DbRead but I think it's the only solution to this)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same `DataReader` for `insert/update` that you used for insertion. You have to close the `DataReader` first before associating some other command with the `DataReader`.

Comment: But when I tried to close the Reader in the classe (so the action is automatic) then I got an error saying that there is no Connection Open on the Update function :S...